# Where are layer 2 transactions (e.g. on Loopring Exchange) actually processed?

Tags: layer-2

If you transact directly on Ethereum network - I get that your transaction is (eventually) processed by the 'world computer' of a load of miners running the Ethereum node software.

If you do a transaction via an L2 protocol like Loopring - where does the off-chain 'stuff' (e.g. validating and rolling up transactions using zero-knowledge proofs before interfacing with the Ethereum network itself) actually happen?

Is it centralised on someone's server somewhere, who runs the calculations before sending the results to be registered on-chain? For instance, Loopring run their own DEX using the Loopring protocol (the Loopring Exchange): where is the compute power for this based / located?

Also aware a lot of the above might be wrong so feel free to point out what mistaken assumptions I've made?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Loopring specially, so let me give you a generic answer instead.

It's basically up to the L2 to decide and it can be anything. Most L2s start with centralized server(s) doing most of the work and slowly work on decentralizing the system. So you send your transaction to some centralized server, magic happens and eventually it ends up as a part of a rollup transaction, in one format or another, in Ethereum L1.

Different L2s offer different kind of guarantees about data & computation correctness, availability, fairness, and so on. And these guarantees change once the project decentralizes more of its pieces.

Even if some of the parts of an L2 are (currently) centralized, you should be able to verify that the centralized parts do their work correctly. So the centralized parts shouldn't be able to cheat - the worst they can do is censor and/or reorganize transactions. How this kind of guarantees are implemented depends again on the L2.